# How do I use ftp.storbinary to upload a file?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am just starting to learn Python. I'm trying to upload a file as follows:

```
import ftplib
myurl = 'ftp.example.com'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
myfile = '/Users/mnewman/Desktop/requested.txt'
ftp = ftplib.FTP(myurl, user, password)
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"
ftp.cwd('/public_html/')
ftp.storbinary('STOR '+myfile, open(myfile, 'rb'))
```

But get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mnewman/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 39, in <module>
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+myfile, open(myfile, 'rb'))
  File "ftplib.pyc", line 487, in storbinary
  File "ftplib.pyc", line 382, in transfercmd
  File "ftplib.pyc", line 348, in ntransfercmd
  File "ftplib.pyc", line 275, in sendcmd
  File "ftplib.pyc", line 248, in getresp
error_perm: 553 Can't open that file: No such file or directory
```

What does "that file" refer to and what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: That is a response message meaning it was generated by the ftp server. Does `/public_html` exist on the target machine and does the ftp server process have rights to write to it?

Comment: What I'm trying to show there is that I can use curl to upload the very same file to the very same directory on the host. There must be a typo or other error in my code, but I can't find it

Comment: Okay, I'm blind. You are using the fully-qualified name on the STOR. That should be the remote name. `ftp.storbinary('STOR requested.txt', open(myfile, 'rb'))` (or use `os.path.split(myfile)[1]`)

Comment: Thank you. Using the remote name worked. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the traceback, the error is deep in the ftp stack processing a response from the server. FTP server messages aren't standardized, but from the text its clear that the FTP server is unable to write the file on the remote side. This can happen for a variety of reasons - perhaps there is a permissions problem (the identity of the FTP server process does not have rights to a target), the write is outside of a sandbox setup on the server, or even that its already open in another program.

But in your case, you are using the full source file name in the "STOR" command when it wants the target path. Depending on whether you want to write subdirectories on the server, calculating the target name can get complicated. If you just want the server's current working directory, you could

```
ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {os.path.split(myfile)[1]}', open(myfile, 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

"That file" refers to the file that you're trying to upload to the FTP. According to your code, it refers to the line: `myfile = '/Users/mnewman/Desktop/requested.txt'`. You get this error because Python can't find the file in the path. Check whether it exists in the correct path. If you want to test whether there is an error in the script, you can add a test file to the directory in which your Python script exists and then run the script with the path of that file.

Example Script for FTP Upload:

```py
import ftplib
session = ftplib.FTP('ftp.example.com','user','password')
file = open('hello.txt','rb')                  # file to send
session.storbinary('STOR hello.txt', file)     # send the file
file.close()                                    # close file and FTP
session.quit()
```

Comment: If that were the case, it would be an `IOError` on the line with the `open`. Instead we see the error is further down the ftp stack in `getresp` - that's a response from the ftp server.